# How to replace a particular String using PowerShell when unexpected white spaces exists?

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I'm having a SQL script (DDL/DML) read through Powershell **Get-Content**. This is assigned to a variable. Now I need to replace certain contents in that script with that of mine.
Example :

Script :

```
**CREATE     TABLE  [dbo].[MyTable]** (
    [MyTableID]     INT NOT NULL,
    [MyTableRecalculated] BIT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MyTableID] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Replace "CREATE     TABLE  [dbo]" with :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'MyTable')
DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
--GO

**CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]** (
```

Encountered Issue :

**CREATE     TABLE  [dbo].[MyTable]** can have multiple white spaces which is restricting me from replacing using -replace in powershell as it will be looking for exact string match.

My Code :

```
    $tempDeltaelement = $Deltaelement -replace 'CREATE TABLE \[dbo\]\.\[([^\]]+)\]', $createwrapperBlock 

Where,
      $Deltaelement =  SQL DML/DDL script read and assigned.
$createwrapperBlock = $createwrapperBlock = @'
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[$1]...'; 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'$1')
DROP TABLE [dbo].[$1]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[$1]
'@
```

Comment: Replace each space in regexp with `[\s\r\n]+`

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work

```
$sql = @"
CREATE     TABLE  [dbo].[MyTable] (
    [MyTableID]     INT NOT NULL,
    [MyTableRecalculated] BIT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MyTableID] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
"@

$sqlDropCreate = @"
IF OBJECT_ID('{0}.{1}') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE {0}.{1};

CREATE TABLE {0}.{1}
"@

$options = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::SingleLine
$capture = [RegEx]::Matches($sql, '\s*CREATE\s*TABLE\s*(\[*\w+\]*)\.(\[*\w+\]*)(.*)', $options)

$schema = $capture.Groups[1].Value
$table  = $capture.Groups[2].Value
$rest   = $capture.Groups[3].Value

$newStart = $sqlDropCreate -f $schema, $table
$newSql = "$newStart$rest"
cls;$newSql
```

The regex matches `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]` with any amount of whitespace between CREATE, TABLE and schema.tablename (the \s* sections). The regex also caters for bracketed or non-bracketed object names, but doesn't check that brackets are on both sides - just includes them if they're there.